# Instance Variables Not Working in Device Controller - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I could not word the title properly but I hope you understand. I have followed the exact example on how to [generate a controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

**My routes:**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

Then copy (new.html.erb) from `devise/sessions` to `views/users/sessions`, then delete the view from `devise/sessions/`

**Then in:**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
     super
    @foo = 'Bar'
  end
end
```

Now in my `views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= @foo %> # should show Bar
```

That not showing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure this only occurs with instance variables? What happens when you set `foo = 'Bar'` in your SessionsController?

Comment: Have not tried that. I'll let you know

Comment: Is @foo = 'Bar' all you have in your  SessionsController#new ? (no `super`?)

Comment: Post updated. Yes super is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your SessionsController should look like:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    @foo = 'bar'
    super
  end
end
```

Note how `super` is below your custom code.

When you call `super`, it calls the parent method; in our case `Devise::SessionsController#new`. You need to initialize `@foo` before calling that method and rendering the `new.html.erb`.

Comment: I'll try that within the hour. Thanks

Comment: Thank you!! I all is well now.